# scheduleOrder API fails in Sterling Order Management

Tags: ibm-sterling

I'm trying to schedule the order, but its keep on failing with the exception "The order line has unscheduled quantity but zero units are available for scheduling." in sterling order management.

The processes that I've done so far are below.

1. Created the Reservation.
2. Created the order, with the ReservationID passed. --> here the order has moved to "Reserved" status.
3. Now I'm trying to schedule the order, by calling scheduleOrder API, but it is getting failed with the above mentioned reason. And now, the order got stuck in "Reserved" status. I'm not able to process the order further.

Any thoughts will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Check in the pipeline configuration, you should have drop the Reserved status from Create order transaction to Schedule order transaction. If you do so, the order will be automatically moved to Scheduled status.